# How to call clang-format from Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, clang, clang-format

I have a Python tool that generates C++ files.

In order to test the tool, I have one test that compares the generated file with an expected output file.

```
diff = difflib.unified_diff(expectedFile.readlines(), file.readlines(), expectedFilename, filename)
```

The problem is that I'm getting some differences due to the format.

I can run clang-format on the expected output file. 
What I'm still trying to do is to run clang-format on the generated files, just before the `difflib.unified_diff` is called.

Can anyone help me on how I can run clang-format in Python on a file ?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `call` command that is supplied by Python to call an external command. For example, you can write a script like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
from subprocess import call
lc = ["clang-format","test.c"] # replace 'test.c' with the your filename.
retcode=call(lc)
sys.exit(retcode);
```